# Create Round Robin in Twilio

Tags: php, mysql, twilio, round-robin

I've searched here and in many forums.  Here's what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to create a system on php/mysql so a twilio phone number on a page will round robin through a list of phone numbers.

The numbers a specific twilio number relates to is this:

555-1212

555-3434

555-5656

555-7878

So it would be something like this:

twilio number called XX time : which number is dialed

1 : 555-1212

2 : 555-3434

3 : 555-5656

4 : 555-7878

5 : 555-1212

6 : 555-3434

etc.

Any advice or pointing me in the correct direction, i would truly appreciate it.  I'm not sure how to or where to turn to help get this done.

Comment: I am trying to so something similar with SMS and Twilio so may be I can help. Can you be a bit more specific with your question so that I can see what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to create a website that has a phone number on it (say, a phone number for a school).  When you call that number, it has different secretary offices (A,B,C,D).  I want to create something where the main number <the twilio number> is called, and then it goes and calls phone number A the first time, the second time someone calls the main number, number B is called, C, then D.  Once D is called (which would be the 4th call), the 5th call goes back to A.

Comment: could you store some sort of timestamp in your database to indicate when was the last time a particular phone no. was called and then based on that, call the next phone no. in the queue ?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

I'd suggest checking out the [Call Screening HowTo](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/callscreening?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) which shows you how to build almost exactly what your describing in PHP.

I believe the only change you would have to make to the sample code is to this line of code:

```
$number_index = isset($_REQUEST['number_index']) ? $_REQUEST['number_index'] : "0";
```

This line checks to see if a parameter named number_index is present and if not sets it to zero.

What you will need to change is to add a second check to see if the number_index is also equal to the last of the array and if it is, set the value to zero so the loop continues.

```
$number_index = isset($_REQUEST['number_index']) ? $_REQUEST['number_index'] : "0";
if ($number_index >= count($number)) $number_index = 0;
```

If course doing this will create an infinite loop, so I'd also suggest adding a way to short circuit that loop.  You could add an additional parameter that lets you track how many times you've looped through your array and once that reaches a max, kills the loop.